# Load a html page in a div by clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image and i want, once i click it, that a particular html page is displayed into a specific div. I found several answer yet, but none of them seems to work.
I'm thinking something simple with jquery, like the answer given here: [display html file in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271584/display-html-file-in-a-div)

What's your solution ?

### Thanks in advance.

EDIT1

I want to load an internal html page ( not an external page from another webiste ) by clicking an image.
This is the code i used taking example from the answer on the link above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("mainscreen").load("/home/dontrythisathome/Programmazione/HTML/Progetto-Corso-Inglese/Misc/FILE/HTML/ChiSiamo.html");}</script>
```

"mainscreen" is the final div when i want to display the html page.
Inside the function .load() there is the path of the html page.
But no html page is displayed into the div.

EDIT2: I found the silly mistake. I use this structure:  when the correct position of the elements is . I could remove also the  element but i'm using CSS and i'm more comfortable to place elements than using  tag options instead. Thanks for all your replies. Tomorrow i'll see if the code with jquery works.

Comment: can you share your html and jquery code that you tried?

Comment: Why does that answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Problem is, that when you load another website using .load(). 
All the other websites CSS/JavaScript gets loaded and yours gets overwritten.

Could you tell us, what you are trying to accomplish? 
Are you loading a html-page from your own website or an external url?

If you dont care for the styles that other website uses, you could do something like this:

```
.load("example.com/some.html #content");
```

This loads the url you specifies and just copys the content of the HTML-Element that corresponds to this selector into your target element. (ONLY INLINE-CSS will be applyed that way, you would need to do that styling manually)

**EDIT: Thank you for updateing your question.**

You are trying to load a file from your filesystem. 
Add file:// in front of the path to your .html file.

NOTE: Especially when you are trying to use AJAX you should use a local website and work with relative paths! This makes it much easier to deploy the website afterwards as you do not have to rewrite all your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdUPr/3/)

Your html code

```
<img class="img" src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif" width=100 height=100>
<div class="targetDiv"></div>
```

Your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img").click(function(){ //capture the event and ignite your work
        loadPage("http://fiddle.jshell.net/"); //call our function
    });
});

function loadPage(link){
    $.get(link,function(data){ //dont forget cross-browser rules.
          $(".targetDiv").append(data) //appended in to your div
    })
};
```

Or you can use `.load` function with link parametre.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have the following HTML code.

```
<div id="mainscreen">click on the image to load html …</div>
<img id="js-image" src="http://cl.ly/image/0A1P1s3r2M0u/Bildschirmfoto%202014-05-24%20um%2021.59.23.png" />
```

And some JavaScript code (with jQuery).

```
var image = document.getElementById('js-image'),
    mainscreen = document.getElementById('mainscreen');

$(image).on('click', function() {
    $(mainscreen).load("http://fiddle.jshell.net/florianpircher/tmRy9/show/");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/florianpircher/6wXBu/1/

You can not use `$("mainscreen")` because that would select `<mainscreen>` and not `#mainscreen`. In jQuery, you need a CSS-selector (like `$("#mainscreen")`).